# java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set error during maven build

Tags: java, linux, maven, applet

**Code**

```
public class Abc extends Applet{

  public Abc(){
   super();
   //some codes
  }
```

**Junit Test**

```
public class AbcTest extends TestCase{

 @Before

 public void setup() throws exception{

  Abc abc = new Abc()
 }

 @Test
// Some test methods.

}
```

**Error**

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.applet.Applet.<init>(Applet.java:75)
```

Build is successful in Windows. 
Is it a linux problem ?

How can I remove this error without removing the complete test class.

Thanks in advance

Abbin

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using classes from awt in a tty without access to an X server.

To circumvent this, pass this option to the JVM: `-Djava.awt.headless=true`.

In Windows, there is always a display, so this is never a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Some Java classes require a display to work properly, it can be a problem under Linux when running outside of a X11 session. One way to overcome this problem is to use xvfb to create a virtual display that will be used when building with maven.

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian, and by default `junit` tries to start a GUI, which gives me this error message. (I guess it wants to display the test results.) You can avoid this by invoking it with the `-text` switch.